# Comparación de listas ordenadas y determinar porcentaje de igualdad tienen en Python

Tags: python

Buen día estoy tratando de comparar 2 listas ordenadas de números, sólo que una de las listas es bidimensional. Necesito validar en orden la `lista_1` con la `lista_2` y determinar el porcentaje de igualdad de cada una de las posiciones de la `lista_2` con la `lista_1`.

Es decir, debo recorrer mi `lista_2` y contar el porcentaje de elementos que coinciden con la `lista_1`. Además, estoy guardando el porcentaje en una nueva lista.

Hasta el momento he intentado esto, sin embargo, no logro la comparación y la suma de la cuenta de los elementos para poder determinar el porcentaje de igualdad

```py
lista_1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
lista_2=[[1,3,4,5,6,8],[1,2,2,3,2,3,],[1,2,3,6,7,8]]
lista_3=['Juan', 'Pedro', 'Lucas']
    
contador = 0

porcentaje= []

for i in lista_1:
    contador = [i]
    for comparacion in lista_2:
        if i in lista_2 :
            contador += 1
        porcentaje.append(contador)
print(porcentaje)
```

Comment: quieres saber si la `lista_2` tiene el mismo orden que la `lista_1`?

Answer (score 0):

lo que quieres es saber el porcentaje de elementos de `lista_1` contiene cada lista de `lista_2`, para eso tendremos que cambiar el ciclo `for` y mover algunas variables, pues tu iteras en los elementos de `lista_1` lo que provoca que al final hagas 6 iteraciones en vez de 3 (que son el numero de listas que contiene `lista_2`)

```py
lista_1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
lista_2=[[1,3,4,5,6,8],[1,2,2,3,2,3,],[1,2,3,6,7,8]]
lista_3=['Juan', 'Pedro', 'Lucas']


porcentajes= []#se almacenara el porcentaje de cada sublista

for lista in lista_2: #iteramos en las listas de lista_2
    contador = 0
    for n in lista_1:#iteramos en los elementos de lista_1
        if n in lista:#si coincide aumentamos el contador
            contador+=1
    #sacamos correctamente el porcentaje
    porcentaje = round((100*contador)/len(subLista),3)
    porcentajes.append(porcentaje)#añadimos el porcentaje
        
print(porcentajes)
```

Movimos el contador dentro del primer ciclo `for` pues si lo dejábamos a fuera el contador iba a seguir aumentando sin depender de la lista, ya que cada lista debe iniciar su contador en `0`